# How hybrid app running on apple watch which made to run on iphones?

Tags: ios, cordova, jquery-mobile, apple-watch, hybrid-mobile-app

i have hybrid ios application(using jquery mobile, cordova) which developed for iphone,Now I want to run the app on apple watch.

What I have to do for this?

Comment: Apple Watch does not have a webview, so hybrid apps will not run. But you can use notifications via plugin.

Comment: This is an FAQ question. You ask first how the app is made for watch, then you will get your answer. https://developer.apple.com/watchkit/

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. PhoneGap needs a WebView which is not available on the watch.